# Androix x86 on Virtualbox, permanent net settings

Tags: java, android, eclipse, virtualbox

I installed Android x86 on Virtualbox on my Win7 pc, to run the apps I create with eclipse in it.

I'm following a tutorial ( [This one](http://www.bobbychanblog.com/2011/07/faster-android-emulator-alternative-using-virtualbox/) ) but I can't get the connecting part right.
When I boot my android virtual machine, i press ALT + F1 and type "netcfg", I see that the "eth0" port has no address and is DOWN.
If I type "dhcpcd" it dynamically gives it an IP so this is the configuration:
`eth0 UP  192.168.10.74`

and that fine, I can proceed to give an "adb connect 192.168.10.74" on Windows' cmd, and it works.

But, when I shut down or reboot the android virtual machine all settings are lost!!! How can I make it work?

Answer (score 0):

There is a change in the step 5 of the process.
Select  **Installation - Install Android-X86 to hard disk**
Hope this solves the problem.

Comment: That's what I did, but it didn't solve the problem, sorry! The problem is with the ethernet configuration. Thanks anyway!